# Why does using glViewport for some GL_QUADS increase my window space area?

Tags: opengl

So I'm doing an exercise which involves graphing something in opengl and then coloring each quadrant. Which I've done it, but when I color the quadrants before graphing my function it makes it bigger than the defined size. Below I leave my code for clarification.

In init I declare the necessary space of `gluOrtho2D(-10,10, -10,10);`

This is in main method that is called by 
`glutDisplayFunc(lineGraph)` If I put this at a top it colors the background but increase the space of the window.
[image]

```
//1 cuadrante
glViewport(125, 375, 250, 250);
glColor3ub(255,255,0);
dibujaFondoCuadrantes();
//2 cuadrante
glViewport(0, 375, 250, 250);
glColor3ub(255,0,0);
dibujaFondoCuadrantes();    

//3 cuadrante
glViewport(125, 250, 250, 250);
glColor3ub(0,255,0);
dibujaFondoCuadrantes();

//4 cuadrante - realmente el 4
glViewport(0, 250, 250, 250);
glColor3ub(0,0,255);
dibujaFondoCuadrantes();
```

Which my method `dibujaFondoCuadrantes()` has:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glVertex2f(-10, 0.0);//Esquina izq arriba
glVertex2f(-10, -10);//Esquina izq abajo
glVertex2f(0.0, -10);// Esquina derecha abajo
glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);//Esquina derecha srriba
glEnd();
```

All my code:

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
// TamaÒo inicial de la ventana
double PI=3.14159265358979;
GLsizei winWidth =600, winHeight =600;
GLint xRaster = 25, yRaster = 150; //posicion inicial de rastreo
GLubyte name[17] = {'G','U','S','T','A','V','O',' ','F','E','R','R','U','F','I','N','O'};
GLubyte matricula[9] = {'A','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
void init(void)
{
glClearColor(0.3,0.7,0.8,1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluOrtho2D(-10,10, -10,10);
}

void dibujaFondoCuadrantes(void){

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
//glColor3f(0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // make this vertex purple
glVertex2f(-10, 0.0);//Esquina izq arriba
glVertex2f(-10, -10);//Esquina izq abajo
glVertex2f(0.0, -10);// Esquina derecha abajo
glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);//Esquina derecha srriba
glEnd();


}


void lineGraph(void)
{
GLint k;
 GLfloat x, f;
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//2 cuadrante
glViewport(0, 375, 250, 250);
glColor3ub(255,0,0);
dibujaFondoCuadrantes();

//1 cuadrante
glViewport(125, 375, 250, 250);
glColor3ub(255,255,0);
dibujaFondoCuadrantes();

//3 cuadrante
glViewport(125, 250, 250, 250);
glColor3ub(0,255,0);
dibujaFondoCuadrantes();

//4 cuadrante - realmente el 4
glViewport(0, 250, 250, 250);
glColor3ub(0,0,255);
dibujaFondoCuadrantes();

      /*
 Añadir codigo para dibujar eje de cordenadas
 */

glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
glLineWidth(3);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
//eje x
glVertex2i(-10,0);
glVertex2i(10,0);
//eje y
glVertex2i(0, -10);
glVertex2i(0, 10);
glEnd();


glPointSize(3);
//Dibuja funcion deseada para actividad 2
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for (x=-6.5; x<=6.5; x+=0.005) {
    glColor3ub(155.0*(x*10), 205.0*x*10,255.0*x*10);
    f=exp(fabs(-x))*cos(2*PI*x);

    glVertex2f(x,f);


}
glEnd();

//Nombre
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
x=0.0;
for (k=0; k<17;k+=1)
{
    glRasterPos2i(-9+k,8);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, name[k]);
}
//Display Matricula
for(k=0;k<9;k+=1){
    glRasterPos2i(-9+k,9);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, matricula[k]);
}


glFlush();

}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(winWidth,winHeight);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow("Gustavo Ferrufino A00812572");
init();

glutDisplayFunc(lineGraph);
//    glutReshapeFunc(winReshapeFcn);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my last glViewport, for quadrant 4, defined also the drawing area for the lines of x and y axis, as well for my function. Therefore the correct thing to do was to set another glViewport. After defining the quadrants, like this:

```
glViewport(0, 0, 600, 600);
```

So it covers all the space of the window.

I also set up my 4  `glViewport` qudrants wrongly since I wasn't using all the space of the window therefore I wasn't setting it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's to do with the calls to glViewport.

Probably before your render function is called, glut is making a glViewport call of effectively glViewport(0,0,winWidth,winHeight).

Your quadrant rendering code is altering glViewport and doesn't restore it afterwards, so the rendering size is affected by the positioning of the glViewport calls.

Comment: GLUT does not do any hidden state changes, so it will leave the viewport as it was.